# When to stop generating cyclic subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Consider the symmetric group $S_6$. When asked to find the cyclic subgroup of $S_6$ generated by $\sigma$=(15)(263)(4), I understand $<\sigma>$ = {$\sigma$,$\sigma^{2}$,$\sigma^{3}$...,$\sigma^{6}$} = {(15)(263),(236),... (1)}, but when expanding this to other groups, how do we know when to stop. In this case we stop when the exponent is equal to six because it is in $S_6$.

Comment: The order of the cyclic subgroup generated by a permutation with cycle lengths $\ell_i$ is $\text{lcm}(\{ \ell_i \})$. You don't need to keep multiplying to see this. In general for a permutation in $S_n$ the largest order can be much more than $n$ (the fact that $6$ works here is a coincidence); see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function .

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The cycles need to be disjoint, of course.

Comment: @Chris: that's part of what "cycle lengths" means.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Right.  You're referring to the _disjoint cycle decomposition_, so to speak.

Comment: @Chris: it's just called the "cycle decomposition": https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cycle_decomposition_for_permutations

Comment: @Qiaochu Duly noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of that cyclic group is $\rm{lcm}(1,2,3)=6$.  Note that we could have, for instance, $(12)(34567)$ which has order $10$ in $S_7$.  Or, $(123)(4567)$ which has order $12$.

In general, the order of an element will divide the order of the group, by a theorem due to Lagrange.  As far as I know that's about all that can be said.

Comment: why do we have lcm(1,2,3)? why those three numbers?

Comment: because those three numbers are the cycle lengths

Comment: those are the lengths of the cycles that make up the permutation $\sigma$